# Focal loss: ValueError: batch_dims = 1 must be less than rank(indices) = 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to re-implement the focal loss function from https://github.com/artemmavrin/focal-loss/ using Tensorflow1.14, but I'm running into the following error while testing with an example -

ValueError: batch_dims = 1 must be less than rank(indices) = 1.

```
probs = tf.gather(probs, y_true, axis=-1, batch_dims=y_true_rank)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update TensorFlow. I had the same error in 2.0.0 but it is OK for 2.4.1.